# How to prevent FreeBSD from disconnecting a drive device?

Tags: freebsd, data-recovery, sata, scsi, ddrescue

While accessing a drive with high error rates (as, for example, [here for opensuse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136945)) in FreeBSD, the system eventually disconnects the drive and it disappears from /dev.  This makes it impossible to run *ddrescue* or *testdrive* in any reasonable fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With FreeBSD 9+ the *camcontrol* utility can be used to control if either a SATA or a SCSI drive is disconnected, or not, in such circumstances:

```
camcontrol negotiate /dev/<dev> -D disable
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [gmountver](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?gmountver); configure it (`gmountver create /dev/adaX`) and use `ddrescue` on `/dev/adaX.mountver`. The `mountver` device will stay there while adaX`` disappears, and all the disk IO operations will get retried after it reappears.

Comment: nice!  that'll go into my toolbox.